# colorbox.close Firebug Error

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have a form inside a colorbox iframe:

```
$(".contact_usModal").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:670, innerHeight:515});
```

I use the above to trigger the link and the colorbox opens fine.

I then want to close the colorbox on submit button clicked and data Posted.
But this is where its tricky because the validator and ajax post i have set up is somehow interfering with the automatic closing of the colorbox on form submit.

```
SubmittingForm=function() { //  form validetd now do the following

var txt = $.ajax({
url: "process.php",
async: true,
type:'POST',
data:({
name:$('input#name').val(),  
email:$('input#email').val()
})  

}).success; 

    // I have tried both options below - they are taken from the colorbox javascript file.

    // Usage format: $.fn.colorbox.close();
    // Usage from within an iframe: parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();

$.fn.colorbox.close();
parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();

        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#myform").validate({
                submitHandler:function(form) {
                    SubmittingForm();
                },
                rules: {
                    name: "required",
                    email: {            
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },

                    },

            });
        });
```

Also just to note, i get this error in firebug:

Permission denied for http://witnessemcee.com to get property Window.$ from http://www.witnessemcee.com. parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();

Thank you.

John

Comment: I'm not sure. But usually it's impossible get properties from parent document across diferent subdomains. www.witnessemcee.com and witnessemecee.com? can you try with the same domain? it's only a posibility... i don't know.

Comment: Try making a function on the parent that closes the colorbox and then call the function from the iframe

Comment: Thanks guys, i have posted my answer inside my question.

Comment: A better idea is to post your answer as, well, an answer, then mark it accepted.

Comment: a even better idea: the comment author make a new answer and then he accept it

Answer (score 0):

> Both comments from you guys worked! It was a subdomain issue as well
>   as a code issue. Here is what i did.
>
> Made my domain redirect to show no www in the address bar, using
>   cpanel but can be done with .htaccess direct.
>
> Also i used this code for the color box close and it worked.
>
> ```
> parent.$.fn.colorbox.close()
> ```

<sub>(Extracted from edited question by OP)</sub>